# FlowLayout which stretches its components

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

As I understand it, the normal `FlowLayout` only uses the `preferredSize` to determine the width and heigt of a component and draws it exactly in these dimensions.

Now I'd like its components so stretch, when space is available and break to a new line, when all the components `minimumSize`s are reached.

Here is an example:

1. Red and Green are my components. These have a `minimumSize` of `100` (symbolized by the yellow line). They are placed in a Layout which is symbolized by the blue background. [This is a big JFrame.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNJMl.gif)
2. I then make my `JFrame` smaller until I reach the `minimumSize`s of the components. [This JFrame is just big enough.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yFQ7.gif)
3. When I make my `JFrame` even smaller, the `FlowLayout` should break into a new line. [The JFrame is now smaller than the components minimum sizes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yUbo.gif)

Is there a LayoutManager in swing who can do that?

Comment: `Is there a LayoutManager in swing who can do that?` - No, you would need to write your own. Maybe start with the FlowLayout code and modify to meet your requirements.